How to design propellers for a contra-rotating system?
Supposing that the thrust requirement and the engine power and RPM are known, is there a way to estimate the propeller diameter and pitch for a contra-rotating arrangement (co-axial)? Also, If both propellers spin with the same RPM, and have the same diameter, how will the pitch change?

Are these contra-rotating propellers also co-axial? They need not be - e.g A400M

Yes, I want to calculate the propeller diameter and pitch if they are co-axial.

Two [non-expert] questions:  1) you'll have an upper limit on diameter for tip speed, right?  2) for conceptual level design sizing, couldn't you treat it like a single prop but just add a handful of % efficiency?

To put it another way, will the thrust produced by a contra-rotating (co-axial) propeller (e.g. two 30"x12.8" props, both spinning at 5000 RPM) be (nearly) double of that produced by a single 30"x12.8" prop spinning at 5000 RPM?
